# C++ code needs to be shortened

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

how if possible can i shorten this down?

```
if(moves[1] == moves[4] && moves[4] == moves[7]) { return 1;}
else if(moves[1] == moves[2] && moves[2] == moves[3]) { return 1;}
else if(moves[4] == moves[5] && moves[5] == moves[6]) { return 1;}
else if(moves[7] == moves[8] && moves[8] == moves[9]) { return 1;}
else if(moves[1] == moves[5] && moves[5] == moves[9]) { return 1;}
else if(moves[3] == moves[5] && moves[5] == moves[7]) { return 1;}
else if(moves[2] == moves[5] && moves[5] == moves[8]) { return 1;}
else if(moves[3] == moves[6] && moves[6] == moves[9]) { return 1;}
else if (moves[1] != '1' && moves[2] != '2' && moves[3] != '3' && moves[4] != '4' && moves[5] != '5' && moves[6] != '6' && moves[7] != '7' && moves[8] != '8' && moves[9] != '9') {
return 2;}
```

in the values moves is stored a X or 0 which is compared to get the winner of the game i need to shorten this down as much as possible,

i cannot think of any way other way to do this due to the random combinations of numbers

The above code is a function called CheckWinner which passes over the input the user has selected with an array of what positions have been filled

The code checks the move[position] against all other combinations of a winning move and returns 1 if a winning move has been detected.

The last bit of code checks all spaces on the grid and if there is no spaces left returns 2 to call a draw.

Hope this helps

Comment: could you elaborate what each thing is?

Comment: See the tag, it's a tic-tac-toe grid.

Comment: @Niels sure but i don't understand it.

Comment: @DanielA.White valid point, I'm also struggling to understand how the grid in tic-tac-toe can get 9 different values hehe. I'm most of all struggling on what the last line is supposed to do.

Comment: There is no apparent _grid_, there's only a one-dimensional array of unknown type.

Comment: Well if I understand correctly he's made a non-zero-based array where the coordinate is translated to an array position as `1+x+(3*y)`. Weird approach to the game though.

Comment: I think it's a history of moves, with `moves[i]` is the character '1' (first) or '2' (second) player with i starting at 1

Comment: sorry will edit will more info, the moves[] are the location of what the user has selected,

Comment: I'm struggling to find any ++ in this C++ question.

Comment: @Amardeep `moves` might be a `std::vector` of something ;-)

Comment: its a basic windows console application i have to do it for my uni assignment, which i don't really want to do due to them refusing to teach us more in C++ just basic cout, fout, arrays and loops then expect us to do this...

Comment: But you're expecting us to do it for you. How do you think we learned to program, by farming out our uni assignments to online slaves?

Comment: [This guy got the same assignment last year I think](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043424/c-scoreboard-of-tic-tac-toe?rq=1), might as well just copy his code.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int winners[8][3] = { {1, 2, 3},
            {4, 5, 6},
            {7, 8, 9},
            {1, 4, 7},
            {2, 5, 8},
            {7, 8, 9},
            {1, 5, 9},
            {3, 5, 7}};

int moves[10] = { 0,
          1, 2, 0,
          0, 2, 0,
          0, 2, 1};

int main()
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<8;++i)
    {
        if (moves[winners[i][0]] == moves[winners[i][1]] &&
            moves[winners[i][1]] == moves[winners[i][2]])
            printf("Player %d wins!\n",moves[winners[i][0]]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The array winners describes various winning combinations and the loop tests each of them.

Answer (score 2):

Not all numbers are random... For the rows, the formula is `N*3+1, N*3+2, N*3+3`, for columns `N+1, N+4, N+7`, etc... where `0 <= N <= 2`. Many other ways to represent it. You can create separate functions to check for rows, columns and diagonals.

Answer (score 1):

Just check the row, column and possibly diagonals for the last play that was made.  You don't need to check over the whole grid.

Also use a two-dimensional array since you're storing a *grid*.  Then loop over rows looking for a match, and loop over columns looking for a match.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename T> bool equal(T a, T b, T c) { return (a==b) && (b==c); }

int foo(char (&moves)[10])
{
    auto eqset = [&](int i1, int i2, int i3) { return equal(moves[i1], moves[i2], moves[i3]); };
    if (eqset(1,4,7) || eqset(1,2,3) || eqset(4,5,6) || eqset(7,8,9) || eqset(1,5,9) || eqset(3,5,7) || eqset(2,5,8) || eqset(3,6,9))
        return 1;
    else if (moves[1] != '1' && moves[2] != '2' && moves[3] != '3' && moves[4] != '4' && moves[5] != '5' && moves[6] != '6' && moves[7] != '7' && moves[8] != '8' && moves[9] != '9') {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Staying quite close to the literal posted code. Note, not all code paths return a value, which is why I stopped short here.

Otherwise, you could proceed with something like:

```
for (int i = 1; i<10; i++)
    if (moves[i] == ('0'+i))
        return 0; // ???

return 2;
```

Comment: 'The question might not actually use C++ but my answer dam well will!'

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will help but I will give it a try:
what I see in your code now at a glance is that most of your conditionals return 1,
only in one case you return 2. So I would just write the if condition for returning 2,
and in *all other cases* return 1, isn't it?

e.g.

```
if (moves[1] != '1' && moves[2] != '2' && moves[3] != '3' && moves[4] != '4' && moves[5] != '5' && moves[6] != '6' && moves[7] != '7' && moves[8] != '8' && moves[9] != '9') {
return 2;}
else
{
// return 1 probably
}
```

hmm... no I take my words back in the above code all other cases will return 1 while in your case there might be situations where you don't want 1 to be returned...

Answer (score 0):

This does the check for a win...  You could probably say it's 'shorter'.

```
// Check rows and columns
for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
    char *row = &moves[3*i+1];
    char *col = &moves[i+1];
    if( row[0] == row[1] && row[0] == row[2] ) return 1;
    if( col[0] == col[3] && col[0] == col[6] ) return 1;
}

// Check diagonals
if( moves[1] == moves[5] && moves[1] == moves[9] ) return 1;
if( moves[3] == moves[5] && moves[3] == moves[7] ) return 1;
```

There are many other ways to do this.  One approach is to simply keep a counter for each row, column and diagonal.  If a cross is played, you add 1 to the relevant counters.  If a naught is played, you subtract 1 from the relevant counters.  If any counter reaches 3 or -3, the game is won.  This takes a very small number of operations for each play.  There is no need to check the entire board.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply shorten your code using a macro:

```
#define comp(i,j,k) (moves[i]==moves[j] && moves[j]==moves[k])
return comp(1,2,3) || comp(4,5,6) || comp(7,8,9)
    || comp(1,5,9) || comp(3,5,7) || comp(2,5,8);
```

Otherwise, you can rotate the board:

```
#define comp(i,j,k) (moves[i]==moves[j] && moves[j]==moves[k])

int rot[6][2] = { {1, 3}, {7, 9}, {9, 1}, {2, 6}, {4, 8}, {2, 8} };
for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
    if (comp(1,2,3) || comp(4,5,6) || comp(1,5,9)))
        return 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        std::swap(moves[rot[i][0]], moves[rot[i][1]]);
}
return 0;
```

Here's the full C++ code, with explanation (it can easily be simple C, not C++, but I like `std::swap`). The board contains meaningless numbers so you can see the rotation:

```
#include <iostream>

void print_tic(int moves[]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i += 3)
        std::cout << moves[i] << moves[i + 1] << moves[i + 2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void rotate(int moves[]) {
    static const int rot[6][2] = {{1, 3}, {7, 9}, {9, 1}, {2, 6}, {4, 8}, {2, 8} };
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        std::swap(moves[rot[i][0]], moves[rot[i][1]]);
}

int comp(int moves[], int i, int j, int k) {
    return moves[i]==moves[j] && moves[j]==moves[k];
}

int main() {
    int moves[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }; //meaningless.

    print_tic(moves);
    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        rotate(moves);
        print_tic(moves);
        if (comp(moves, 1,2,3)  // first row
             || comp(moves, 4,5,6)  // second row - forget that earlier
             || comp(moves, 1,5,9)) // main diagon
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

with the printings, you can see the rotations:

```
123
456
789

741
852
963

987
654
321

369
258
147

123
456
789
```

You can rotate only once, at the expnse of one more `comp()` for the third line.